# Starting .bin file as an executable

Tags: c++, windows, console

I'm writing a console program for Windows and I need to open another program. My problem is that the executable of this program has the `.bin` extension and my code won't open it as a program.

Also, when my console is starting I'd like to hide it. I've written some code to do this but it appears and then quickly dissapears.

My code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow(); 
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE ); 
    system("start client.bin --argument");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just rename the file, giving it another extension like `.exe`?

Comment: g00gle is your friend (in this case), http://www.wikihow.com/Open-BIN-Files

Comment: I need it to be .bin...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, its an executable with .bin extension. Please read my post again :).

Comment: Seems like an XY question - what exactly is in the .bin file, and what is the overall problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @AndreiVlad: Well then, if `start` doesn't handle it then probably `ShellExecute` doesn't either, because the `start` command is mainly just a way to invoke the function. So, try `CreateProcess` directly. But do check the file headers with e.g. `dumpbin` (Microsoft tools), be sure that it's an executable.

Comment: That .bin file its an application that i want to open with an argument. But i need it to keep the .bin extension. The overall problem its that i cant open the application as .bin, the system will open it will VLC media player for example. Thanks!

Comment: How did the file get a name ending with `.bin` (i.e., how exactly did you create it)? And why do you need it to have the `.bin` extension? This definitely smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), but there's not enough information for me to guess what X is. It seems to be Windows-specific, so I'll add that tag.

Comment: If `client.bin` is in the current directory or a `PATH` directory, then cmd will always try `CreateProcess` first before trying `ShellExecuteEx` -- regardless of extension. If `CreateProcess` fails then this file is not a PE executable. Whatever it is will need a shell-registered association for .bin files to allow `ShellExecuteEx` to work.

Comment: @eryksun: Setting up a shell-registered association for `.bin` files is probably a bad idea. The `.bin` suffix means "binary", and it's used for a number of different kinds of files created by various programs -- and I don't think I've ever seen it used for executables. Telling the OS to treat all `.bin` files as executables will most likely cause numerous problems, and solve none.

Comment: @KeithThompson, the OP says `start` fails. Unless this file can't be found in the current directory or in a `PATH` directory, that tells us that `CreateProcess` failed, so this "bin" type is not a PE executable. If a shell `"open"` verb isn't added with the command line for whatever program is required to open this bin file using `ShellExecuteEx`, then it'll just have to be run explictly with the required command line.

Comment: The OP hasn't explained why the file has a `.bin` extension, or why it *needs* to have a `.bin` extension.

Comment: @KeithThompson, cmd will always call `CreateProcess` if it can find the file in the current directory or a `PATH` directory (possibly with an extension from `PATHEXT` appended to the name). `CreateProcess` itself doesn't care what the extension is. If it fails, cmd tries `ShellExecuteEx`, which will search several registry keys to find an associated command to open the filetype. You're right that .bin is probably already associated (e.g. .bin/.cue files for disk images), so the OP needs to manually specify the particular command to open this .bin file.

Comment: @eryksun: It's true that with a direct command [cmd.exe] looks at the file headers and recognizes a PE executable as such. But I doubt that the `start` command tries `CreateProcess` first. Where do you get that information?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, cmd doesn't read the PE header from the file. If `start` isn't used in the interactive command prompt, then cmd does need to know whether the child process is a console process that it has to wait on. Since the process could have been started using some other executable via `ShellExecuteEx`, it prefers to call `ReadProcessMemory` to read the child's process environment block (PEB) to get its `ImageSubsystem` value (2 is GUI; 3 is console).

Comment: So there isn't now way to open a executable with .bin extension with an argument?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, as to `start` calling `CreateProces`, just attach a debugger to cmd and see for yourself. If the file is found via `cmd!SearchForExecutable`, then even `start` first tries `CreateProces`. Except if it finds a directory it skips `CreateProcess` because that would be pointless. If the file isn't found then it tries `ShellExecuteEx` anyway since, for example, it could be an `App Paths` command.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you should run your test under a debugger to see that it's calling `CreateProcess`, which is what reads the file and tries to run it as an old 16-bit DOS executable (my 64-bit Windows doesn't have the NTVDM virtual DOS machine, so that wouldn't work for me even if it was a valid DOS executable).

Comment: @eryksun: OK, it took some time before I saw what you meant. Sorry. Essentially the PE header checking is done by (delegated to) `CreateProcess`. Makes sense in a way. Notably Winodws Explorer does not do that, e.g. a `.txt` file starting with MZ is opened via its association when it's double-clicked.